# What has happened to javascript helper in cakePHP 2?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have used this [item](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/agusti/2010/02/02/transparent-datepicker-with-jquery) and get this error :

```
Missing Helper
Error: JavascriptHelper could not be found.
Error: Create the class JavascriptHelper below in file: app/View/Helper/JavascriptHelper.php
<?php
     class JavascriptHelper extends AppHelper {
 }
```

Well indeed, this file does not exists, and I tried to use 'Js' in my helper array.

```
class myClassController expend AppController {
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Js'); // and not 'Javascript');
```

In the code, the method `$this->Javascript->codeBlock` is called to add a javascript method (in the middle of the content instead of the header) but there is no $this->Js->codeBlockcodeBlock either.

```
$output .= $this->Js->codeBlock("datepick('" . $htmlAttributes['id'] . "','01/01/" . $options['minYear'] . "','31/12/" . $options['maxYear'] . "');");
```

Could you explain me what happened to the old Javascript helper or how to get the code working?

Is there an other helper which could work with CakePHP-2.0?

Cordially,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you read the migration guide? If not do that now:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#xmlhelper-ajaxhelper-and-javascripthelper-removed

> XmlHelper, AjaxHelper and JavascriptHelper removed The AjaxHelper and
>   JavascriptHelper have been removed as they were deprecated in version
>   1.3. The XmlHelper was removed, as it was made obsolete and redundant with the improvements to Xml. The Xml class should be used to replace
>   previous usage of XmlHelper.
>
> The AjaxHelper, and JavascriptHelper are replaced with the JsHelper
>   and HtmlHelper.
>
> JsHelper JsBaseEngineHelper is now abstract, you will need to
>   implement all the methods that previously generated errors.

So

```
$this->Js->codeBlock('...');
```

is now

```
$this->Html->codeBlock('...');
```

Comment: If XmlHelper is no longer there, it's assumed that it will work just fine then without doing public $helpers = array('Xml'); ? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlHelper::scriptBlock($code, $options = array())
    //Parameters:   

    $code (string) – The code to go in the script tag.
    $options (array) – An array of html attributes.
```

Comment: Yes, but the notable thing is that the function is now in HtmlHelper and not any more in the JavascriptHelper which has been made obsolete.